# Tag merge / synonym request: [internationalisation] → [internationalization]

Tags: support, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

Please merge [internationalisation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internationalisation) (3 questions) into [internationalization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internationalization) (25), and make them synonyms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have approved the synonym.

I will merge them later.